# Material UI React Autocomplete TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I copied pasted the demo from [here](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) but it doesn't seem to work in my app. Not sure what is different from my code and the code on the website. I get these errors:

```
react-dom.development.js:14724  Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

VM15341 makeStyles.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined

react-dom.development.js:22940 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDidCatch' of null
```

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
];

class CollectionPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Autocomplete
          id="combo-box-demo"
          options={top100Films}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
          style={{ width: 300 }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CollectionPage;
```

Comment: did u use makestyles?

Comment: i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try deleting your node_modules folder and reinstall.

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Also, ensure you are not running a project, in another react project, as that will cause duplicate copies of react and react-dom.

There's no problem with the codes because the codes is working here -> [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-leakey-j4dz3?file=/src/App.js)